# How to delete values in a dict based on the presence of child values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dict that looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('arguments', {'index': 1, 'parent': None}), ('controls', {'index': 2, 'parent': None}), ('examples', {'index': 3, 'parent': None}), ('journal', {'index': 4, 'parent': None}), ('journal/config', {'index': 5, 'parent': 'journal'}), ('journal/journaltest', {'index': 6, 'parent': 'journal'}), ('procs', {'index': 7, 'parent': None}), ('processor', {'index': 8, 'parent': None}), ('prediction', {'index': 9, 'parent': None}), ('reports', {'index': 10, 'parent': None}), ('tooki', {'index': 11, 'parent': None}), ('tooki/help', {'index': 12, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/lime', {'index': 13, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/medium', {'index': 14, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/share', {'index': 15, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/trigger', {'index': 16, 'parent': 'tooki'})])
```

How can I iterate over the elements of this dict, and exclude any element that has "'parent' : None" **and** no child element (meaning, no other element in this dict has this one as a parent).

Expected output:

```
OrderedDict([('journal', {'index': 4, 'parent': None}), ('journal/config', {'index': 5, 'parent': 'journal'}), ('journal/journaltest', {'index': 6, 'parent': 'journal'}), ('tooki', {'index': 11, 'parent': None}), ('tooki/help', {'index': 12, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/lime', {'index': 13, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/medium', {'index': 14, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/share', {'index': 15, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/trigger', {'index': 16, 'parent': 'tooki'})])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function can help you

```
def orderedDict(data_list: list):
    result: list = []
    for data in data_list:
        is_ok = True
        if data[1]["parent"] is None:
            is_ok = False
            for item in [x[0] for x in [y for y in data_list if y[0] != data[0]]]:
                if data[0]+"/" in item:
                    is_ok = True
                    break
        if is_ok:
            result.append(data)
    return result
```

To use it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = ([('arguments', {'index': 1, 'parent': None}), ('controls', {'index': 2, 'parent': None}),
             ('examples', {'index': 3, 'parent': None}), ('journal', {'index': 4, 'parent': None}),
             ('journal/config', {'index': 5, 'parent': 'journal'}),
             ('journal/journaltest', {'index': 6, 'parent': 'journal'}), ('procs', {'index': 7, 'parent': None}),
             ('processor', {'index': 8, 'parent': None}), ('prediction', {'index': 9, 'parent': None}),
             ('reports', {'index': 10, 'parent': None}), ('tooki', {'index': 11, 'parent': None}),
             ('tooki/help', {'index': 12, 'parent': 'tooki'}), ('tooki/lime', {'index': 13, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
             ('tooki/medium', {'index': 14, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
             ('tooki/share', {'index': 15, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
             ('tooki/trigger', {'index': 16, 'parent': 'tooki'})])
    result = orderedDict(data_list=data)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ins = OrderedDict(...)

parents = set(elem['parent'] for elem in ins.values() if elem['parent'] is not None)

d = OrderedDict()
for key, value in ins.items():
    if value['parent'] is not None:
        d[key] = value
    elif any(ins.get(k) is not None for k in parents):
        d[key] = value
```

Using a set of parent keys remove lot of complexity. In your case, there are lot of elements, but only two keys will be checked.

Answer (score 0):

A really dumb way of doing this:

```py
x = OrderedDict(blah blah blah)

keys_to_exclude = []
for key1, val1 in x.items():
    if val1['parent'] is None:
        remove = True
        for key2, val2 in x.items():
            if val2['parent'] == key1:
                remove = False  
        if remove:
            keys_to_exclude.append(key1)

for key in keys_to_exclude:
    x.pop(key, None)
```

This code obviously had O(n^2) complexity. A smarter way of doing this would be adding a 'child' key for each element beforehand and the complexity would be O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that working for me. The order of the final output is not the same, but I was able to meet the requirement of excluding the `key value` pairs according to the conditions you had mentioned.

```
a = OrderedDict([('arguments', {'index': 1, 'parent': None}),
                 ('controls', {'index': 2, 'parent': None}),
                 ('examples', {'index': 3, 'parent': None}),
                 ('journal', {'index': 4, 'parent': None}),
                 ('journal/config', {'index': 5, 'parent': 'journal'}),
                 ('journal/journaltest', {'index': 6, 'parent': 'journal'}),
                 ('procs', {'index': 7, 'parent': None}),
                 ('processor', {'index': 8, 'parent': None}),
                 ('prediction', {'index': 9, 'parent': None}),
                 ('reports', {'index': 10, 'parent': None}),
                 ('tooki', {'index': 11, 'parent': None}),
                 ('tooki/help', {'index': 12, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
                 ('tooki/lime', {'index': 13, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
                 ('tooki/medium', {'index': 14, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
                 ('tooki/share', {'index': 15, 'parent': 'tooki'}),
                 ('tooki/trigger', {'index': 16, 'parent': 'tooki'})])
od = OrderedDict()
for each in a:
    if (parent := a[each].get('parent', None)):
        od[parent] = a[parent]

for each in a:
    if (element := a[each].get('parent', None)):
        od[each] = a[each]

print(od)
```

I did not comprehension for simplicity of understanding the code. The first loop saves the parents to a new `OrdereDict`. The second saves the children. Do let me know if your requirements are not met.